# How to fix this error Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active?

Tags: php, pdo

Hello i have a realy problem on webhost with this error ( check full error ) =>  https://postimg.cc/5QQHM5Rq
live: http://abc.highcodelex.ro/ ( you can register user and see the error, the row is inserted but display the errors)

On local machine with xampp and windows 10 its work corectly.. without any problems, i dont know how to fix it, here i have the Database Class..

```
<?php
namespace Core;
use \PDO;
use \PDOException;
use Core\Helpers;

class Database {
  private static $_instance = null;
  private $_pdo, $_query, $_error = false, $_result, $_count = 0, $_lastInsertID = null, $_fetchStyle = PDO::FETCH_OBJ;

  private function __construct() {
    try {
      $this->_pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
      $this->_pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $this->_pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
      $this->_pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
    } catch(\PDOException $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }

  public function query($sql, $params = [],$class = false) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
      $x = 1;
      if(count($params)) {
        foreach($params as $param) {
          $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
          $x++;
        }
      }
      if($this->_query->execute()) {
        if($class && $this->_fetchStyle === \PDO::FETCH_CLASS){
          $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll($this->_fetchStyle,$class);
        } else {
          $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll($this->_fetchStyle);
        }
        $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        $this->_lastInsertID = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
      } else {
        $this->_error = true;
      }
    }
    return $this;
  }

  protected function _read($table, $params=[],$class) {
    $columns = '*';
    $joins = "";
    $conditionString = '';
    $bind = [];
    $order = '';
    $limit = '';
    $offset = '';

    //FETCH STYLE
    if(isset($params['fetchStyle'])){
      $this->_fetchStyle = $params['fetchStyle'];
    }

    // conditions
    if(isset($params['conditions'])) {
      if(is_array($params['conditions'])) {
        foreach($params['conditions'] as $condition) {
          $conditionString .= ' ' . $condition . ' AND';
        }
        $conditionString = trim($conditionString);
        $conditionString = rtrim($conditionString, ' AND');
      } else {
        $conditionString = $params['conditions'];
      }
      if($conditionString != '') {
        $conditionString = ' Where ' . $conditionString;
      }
    }

    // columns
    if(array_key_exists('columns',$params)){
      $columns = $params['columns'];
    }

    if(array_key_exists('joins',$params)){
      foreach($params['joins'] as $join){
        $joins .= $this->_buildJoin($join);
      }
      $joins .= " ";
    }

    // bind
    if(array_key_exists('bind', $params)) {
      $bind = $params['bind'];
    }

    // order
    if(array_key_exists('order', $params)) {
      $order = ' ORDER BY ' . $params['order'];
    }

    // limit
    if(array_key_exists('limit', $params)) {
      $limit = ' LIMIT ' . $params['limit'];
    }

    // offset
    if(array_key_exists('offset', $params)) {
      $offset = ' OFFSET ' . $params['offset'];
    }
    $sql = "SELECT {$columns} FROM {$table}{$joins}{$conditionString}{$order}{$limit}{$offset}";
    if($this->query($sql, $bind,$class)) {
      if(!count($this->_result)) return false;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function find($table, $params=[],$class=false) {
    if($this->_read($table, $params,$class)) {
      return $this->results();
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function findFirst($table, $params=[],$class=false) {
    if($this->_read($table, $params,$class)) {
      return $this->first();
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function insert($table, $fields = []) {
    $fieldString = '';
    $valueString = '';
    $values = [];

    foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
      $fieldString .= '`' . $field . '`,';
      $valueString .= '?,';
      $values[] = $value;
    }
    $fieldString = rtrim($fieldString, ',');
    $valueString = rtrim($valueString, ',');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fieldString}) VALUES ({$valueString})";
    if(!$this->query($sql, $values)->error()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function update($table, $id, $fields = []) {
    $fieldString = '';
    $values = [];
    foreach($fields as $field => $value) {
      $fieldString .= ' ' . $field . ' = ?,';
      $values[] = $value;
    }
    $fieldString = trim($fieldString);
    $fieldString = rtrim($fieldString, ',');
    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$fieldString} WHERE id = {$id}";
    if(!$this->query($sql, $values)->error()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function delete($table, $id) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = {$id}";
    if(!$this->query($sql)->error()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function results() {
    return $this->_result;
  }

  public function first() {
    return (!empty($this->_result))? $this->_result[0] : [];
  }

  public function count() {
    return $this->_count;
  }

  public function lastID() {
    return $this->_lastInsertID;
  }

  public function get_columns($table) {
    return $this->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table}")->results();
  }

  public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
  }

  protected function _buildJoin($join=[]){
    $table = $join[0];
    $condition = $join[1];
    $alias = $join[2];
    $type = (isset($join[3]))? strtoupper($join[3]) : "INNER";
    $jString = "{$type} JOIN {$table} {$alias} ON {$condition}";
    return " " . $jString;
  }
}
```

And line 44 its this line... also i have on live the php info if someone need ..

```
$this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll($this->_fetchStyle);
```

This is the error if you don't want to see on live..

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. in  /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/core/Database.php:44
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/core/Database.php(44): PDOStatement->fetchAll(8) #1 /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/core/Database.php(151): Core\Database->query('INSERT INTO use...', Array) #2 /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/core/Model.php(157): Core\Database->insert('users', Array) #3 /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/core/Model.php(132): Core\Model->insert(Array) #4 /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/app/controllers/RegisterController.php(52): Core\Model->save() #5 [internal function]: App\Controllers\RegisterController->index() #6 /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/core/Router.php(35): in /home3/r79007high/abc.highcodelex.ro/core/Database.php on line 44

For example this action i have in controller

```
public function index() {
    $newUser = new Users();
    if($this->request->isPost()) {
      $this->request->csrfCheck();
      $newUser->assign($this->request->get(),Users::blackListedFormKeys);
      $newUser->confirm =$this->request->get('confirm');
      if($newUser->save()){
        Router::redirect('register/login');
      }
    }
    $this->view->newUser = $newUser;
    $this->view->displayErrors = $newUser->getErrorMessages();
    $this->view->render('register/register');
  }
```

And in Core\Model this two action save and assign

```
public function save() {
    $this->validator();
    $save = false;
    if($this->_validates){
      $this->beforeSave();
      $fields = $this->getColumnsForSave();
      // determine whether to update or insert
      if($this->isNew()) {
        $save = $this->insert($fields);
        // populate object with the id
        if($save){
          $this->id = static::getDb()->lastID();
        }
      } else {
        $save = $this->update($fields);
      }
      // run after save
      if($save){
        $this->afterSave();
      }
    }
    return $save;
  }

public function assign($params,$list=[],$blackList=true) {
    foreach($params as $key => $val) {
      // check if there is permission to update the object
      $whiteListed = true;
      if(sizeof($list) > 0){
        if($blackList){
          $whiteListed = !in_array($key,$list);
        } else {
          $whiteListed = in_array($key,$list);
        }
      }
      if(property_exists($this,$key) && $whiteListed){
        $this->$key = $val;
      }
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

Comment: and what you suppose to fetch from the *insert* query?

Comment: Normal after inserting the application should redirect you and process other data from db for display

Comment: Let me repeat my question: you are running an INSERT query, and then calling fetchAll(). What are you trying to fetch?

Comment: Sorry..in  User Model i have loginUserFromCookie and i trying to fetch user object if exist.
Here is the full code : https://bitbucket.org/highcodelex/ecommerce/src/master/

Comment: I have to ask again. You are NOT calling loginuserfromcookie. You are calling insert () method which is running   INSERT query, as it can be seen from the error message. Why are you calling fetch after insert query?

Comment: i need to get this results before insert or update, this is getColumnsForSave() function from save()
return $this->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table}")->results();

P.S. i store this results in $fields and i pass wthis $fields in insert method

Comment: You should rewrite your query() function. You shouldn't call fetchall() after any query, but only after select.

Comment: Ok thank you, and sorry for this i'm very tired.. I didn't expect any problems to appear when uploading to the webhost